# How do I know whether a site is a daughter site of another?

Tags: web-development

Give [site 1](http://www.ocfaustralia.org/) and [site 2](http://griffith.ocfaustralia.org/), is there a way for me to tell whether site 2 is a daughter site for site 1? That is, if I were to remove site 1 would site 2 go down as well? The reason I'm asking is because I've been asked to do a major redesign for site 1 (the original developer's gone, left no documentations, the codes disorganised and everywhere, etc) and with the way things are, I figured it would be a lot easier and also better in the long run if I just delete everything and start again from scratch. Therefore I need to check for dependancies before pulling the plug.